# SwiftUI + CoreData: Insert more than 1000 entities with relationships

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a SwiftUI project in which I'm using CoreData to save data fetched from an API into the device. I was trying to insert the entities in batches which worked fine until I realized that the relationships when inserting in batched are "untouched":

- An entity `Job`, which has a one-to-many relationship with the entity `Tag.`
- A one-to-one relationship with `Category`.
- A one-to-one relationship with `Type`.

What I'm doing now is inserting the entities manually in a background task:

```
container.performBackgroundTask { context in
            for job in jobs {
                let jobToInsert = Job(context: context)
                let type = JobType(context: context)
                let category = Category(context: context)
                
                jobToInsert.id = Int32(job.id)
                ....
                do {
                    print("Inserting jobs")
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    // log any errors
                }
}
```

Is there any way to improve the performance by perhaps doing this in a way that I don't know? Because for the user, when they start the app, inserting the jobs one by one isn't a very nice experience because first, it takes a long time (more than 2 minutes) and second because my UI isn't automatically updated as I'm inserting the entities.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I also see the memory increasing and after taking the screenshot and before I stopped the process, I saw the memory in 1.09 GB

[image]

EDIT 2: This is the code I used when trying to insert the jobs in batch:

```
private func newBatchInsertRequest(with jobs: [JobCodable]) -> NSBatchInsertRequest {
        var index = 0
        let total = jobs.count
        let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(
            entity: Job.entity()) { (managedObject: NSManagedObject) -> Bool in
                guard index < total else { return true }
                if let job = managedObject as? Job {
                    let type = JobType(context: self.container.viewContext)
                    let category = Category(context: self.container.viewContext)
                    let data: JobCodable = jobs[index]
                    job.id = Int32(data.id)
...
return batchInsert
```

Unfortunately, the relationship can't be built due probably to the context? since I'm getting `Thread 13: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` in the line `let category = Category(context: self.container.viewContext)`

Comment: What do you mean with "untouched" and have looked into using NSBatchInsertRequest?

Comment: sorry my bad, I should have never used that terms. I will update my question

Comment: You can try making your CoreData entities [Codable](https://medium.com/swlh/core-data-using-codable-68660dfb5ce8) and use the standard decoders.

Comment: @loremipsum what would that do?

Comment: Make the whole conversion from your API more straight forward by letting the decoder to the work and maybe get right of that bad instruction error. 1000 entities with relationships seems like there is a huge potential for typos and such. Look at the link I provided with the word "Codable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `save()` on the context for every job that you insert? If so, I would start there — if you want to load a bunch of jobs all at once, you can insert all your Job instances, set up the relationships, and then only `save()` once at the very end (outside the loop).

This will not only save you time, but also make it appear as if all the objects show up at the same time to your UI. If that's not what you want, you can experiment with saving in batches within the loop — only call `save()` every thousand Job objects, for example.

Comment: Calling `save()` for every job is what makes this slow and sluggish. Indeed I'm interested in loading a bunch of jobs all at once, so I moved the `save()` out of the job creation loop and the app is responsive again, except that I don't see anything in my `List` of jobs.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue — you'll want to make sure that (1) your view context is configured to merge changes from background contexts, so that the new `Job` objects are reflected in the view context, and (2) your UI is set up to change when your view context has object changes, using a fetched results controller or similar.

Comment: I have `container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` and I'm using a `@FetchRequest` in my SwiftUI view that fetches all the jobs - that should be enough shouldn't it?